# createQueryBuilder IN clause

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I´m working with Symfony2 and I need to execute this SQL for example:

> ```
>       select detformacion.* from detformacion
>         left  join formacion
>         on detformacion.formacion_id = formacion.id
>         left join detcurso
>         on formacion.id = detcurso.formacion_id
>         where detcurso.id IN ('143','144');
> ```

For that, I have this in my Repository:

> public function getSeleccion() {

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('d')
            ->from('GitekUdaBundle:Detformacion', 'd')
            ->leftJoin('d.formacion', 'f') 
                ->leftJoin('f.detcursos', 'det')
                ->where('det.id = :miarray')
                ->setParameter('miarray',array('143','144'))
            ->getQuery() 
            ;
      return $query->getResult();
    }
```

I tried with ->where('det.id IN :miarray') but I´m getting errors all the time.

Any help or clue?

thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The problem is setting the parameters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Missing parentheses after the IN operator :

```
->where('det.id IN (:miarray)')
->setParameter('miarray', array('143','144'))
```